# how to set pom.xml to download artifact from nexus remote repository

Tags: maven, pom.xml, nexus

I want to set a remote nexus repository with my local repository in maven, when a artifact is not in the local repository, then it should be downloaded from my remote repository and should be installed to the local repository. How can I set it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add a repository section to your pom.

Here is an example:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>browserid-snapshots</id>
        <name>browserid-snapshots</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Taken from here https://github.com/user454322/browserid-verifier/blob/e7b81495882312c8cd9f1fb7e8313e239a6b3238/sample/pom.xml#L67-L73

Check the *Repository* section on the [POM Reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repository) for more info.

Comment: but where should I set the username and password to my nexus remote repository?\

Comment: That goes in your `settings.xml` file.

http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers.

Answer (score 0):

you can define your remote-repo in your POM; however, in most cases you will use the same remote repo in all your projects, so instead of defining it over and over again in all you POMs, you can set it in the settings.xml %MAVEN_HOME%/conf/settings.xml

```
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>plt-release</id>
          <name>my-release</name>
          <url>http://<ip>:<port>/artifactory/release-local</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots/>
          <id>plt-snapshot</id>
          <name>my-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://<ip>:<port>/artifactory/snapshot-local</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>

  </profiles>
```